# How to play a sound in a Jquery loop (metronome)?

Tags: jquery, audio

I'd like to make a metronome using jquery, with a **clicking sound** and a color to visualize the tempo. At that point, the visual part works fine, but i have a problem with the sound.

Can't make it work, it is supposed to beep as many times per minutes as the selected tempo.

Here is the code :

```
$(function(){
var intervalReference = 0;

var metronomeTick = function() {
    $("#metronome").stop();
    $("#metronome").animate({opacity: 1},
        30,                            
        function() { $(this).animate({opacity:0});
        $("#beep").append('autostart', 'true');
    }
    );
};

$(function() {
    var slider = $("#bpm").slider({
        min: 40,
        max: 240,
        value: 120,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            clearInterval(intervalReference);
            intervalReference = setInterval(metronomeTick, 1000*60/ui.value);
            $("#bpmshow").text("bpm: " + ui.value);
        }
    });
});
});
```

HTML :

```
<div id="bpm"></div>
<span id="bpmshow"></span>
<div id="metronome"></div>
<embed id="beep" src="timer.wav" hidden="true" loop="true" autostart="false">
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well, i was on the wrong way.

I wanted to hear the sound each time my *visual* div was displayed. The problem was I used the `animate()` function to do this, and it couldn't trigger the `play()` event.

I've rewritten the code using `window.setTimeout()` to control the timing, and `play()` to load and play the *beep* thanks to the HTML5 `<audio>` tag.

Sorry can't explain more, the script is still not finished yet.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#beep").append('autostart', 'true');` appends text to the element. You probably want to set the autostart attribute itself:

```
$("#beep").attr('autostart', 'true');
```

Comment: thanks but it still doesn't work. It's like the sound isn't in the loop. Maybe i'm on the wrong way trying to use the embed tag instead of something else.

Comment: jQuery has a sound plugin, give it a try.